# How to mark dates which are in the past?

Tags: text-processing, sed, date

From the answers I updated the question:

Now, it's:

```
$ date "+%F %H:%M"
2014-06-04 11:26
```

This is the input:

```
$ cat input.txt 
<tr><td>2014-04-24 14:01</td><td>2014-06-04 11:30</td><td>2014-06-04 11:23</td></tr>
```

This is the current perl script (that is working GREAT!, only hours/minutes missing)

```
$ cat a.txt 
perl -MTime::Piece -pe '
    BEGIN {$today = localtime->ymd}
    @days = $_ =~ /<td>(.+?)<\/td>/g;
    for $d (@days) {
      $_ =~ s!$d!<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>$d</font>!g if $d lt $today;
      }' input.txt
```

And now, it produces this output:

```
$ bash a.txt 
<tr><td><font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>2014-04-24 14:01</font></td><td>2014-06-04 11:30</td><td>2014-06-04 11:23</td></tr>
```

**Our question**: How can we mark the past dates - the hours:minutes too! - as red? The current perl solution need to be updated since it doesn't marks the "2014-06-04 11:23" red, but it's a past date!

p.s.: 
- several dates could be in one line - that is working
- past days marked as red - that is working
- I tried to use the "datetime" instead of "ymd" ( http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html ) - but it didn't worked, probably because of that in the input.txt there are " " instead of "\t"? 
- +just a note, I already found out how to mark tomorrow:

```
sed -i "s/<td>\(`date +%F -d '+1 day'`\)/<td><font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:lightgreen>\1<\/font>/g" in.txt
```

Comment: It's just sticking more precisely to the $subject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another `perl` solution, use `Time::Piece` module like @choroba's answer:

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -pe '
BEGIN {$today = localtime->ymd." ".localtime->hms}
    s!($1)!<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>$1</font>!g
    if /<td>(.+?)<\/td>/g and $1 lt $today;
' in.txt
asfsaf<td><font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red></font> kjycasfd
FKZF<td>2014-05-09 lkjafsa
sdfg<td>2014-05-13 asdf
sfjlaslfsaljf <td><font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red></font> DIJIZLOF
```

**Update**

If you have several past date in one line, try:

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -pe '
    BEGIN {$today = localtime->ymd." ".localtime->hms}
        @days = $_ =~ /<td>(.+?)<\/td>/g;
        for $d (@days) {
          $_ =~ s!$d!<font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>$d</font>! if $d lt $today;
      }' in.txt
<tr><td><font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>2014-04-24 00:01</font></td><td>2014-06-24 00:01</td><td><font style=BACKGROUND-COLOR:red>2014-05-13 00:00</font></td></tr>
```

**Explanation**

- We save all date in a line in `@days` array.
- For each date, we check if it less than today then replace it.

Comment: I did an update, we found a thing

Comment: @evachristine: Updated my answer.

Comment: I updated the Q :\

Comment: Updated answer too.

Comment: +only a "g" needed after the "!", but it works!! YEAH

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
< in.txt perl -MTime::Piece -pe '
    BEGIN { $t = localtime->ymd }
    if (/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/ and $1 lt $t) {
        s=($1)=<red>$1</red>=g
    }'
```

Basically, the `ymd` method of [Time::Piece](http://p3rl.org/Time%3a%3aPiece) returns the current date in the expected format. You can then use plain string comparison to get past dates.

*UPDATE*: To process multiple dates per line, you have to change the code:

```
< in.txt perl -MTime::Piece -pe '
    BEGIN { $t = localtime->ymd }
    push @d, $1 while /([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/g;
    for my $d (@d) {
        $d lt $t and s=($d)=<red>$1</red>=g;   
    }'
```

Comment: I did an update, we found a thing

Comment: @evachristine: updated, too.

Comment: I updated the Q :\